# Redis - server closed the connection / can't connect

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm trying to get redis running locally. It works fine sometimes, but sometimes I have this problem when starting it. It appears to start fine, but then I can't make any connections to it or use the command line tool. I can't understand why there would be no errors when starting redis, it says its running on 6379, but won't respond on that port.

````
Toms-MBP:tinder-art tomchambers$ redis-server
[86521] 23 Apr 18:37:22.427 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
[86521] 23 Apr 18:37:22.429 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 256).
                _._                                                  
           _.-``__ ''-._                                             
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 2.8.19 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._                                   
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in stand alone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 86521
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io        
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |                                  
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'                                       
          `-._        _.-'                                           
              `-.__.-'                                               

[86521] 23 Apr 18:37:22.431 # Server started, Redis version 2.8.19
[86521] 23 Apr 18:37:22.432 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
[86521] 23 Apr 18:37:22.432 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379

Toms-MBP:tinder-art tomchambers$ redis-cli monitor
Error: Server closed the connection


^CToms-MBP:tinder-art tomchambers$ node app.js
Connecting to local redis
Connecting to local redis
Server started 3000
Redis error: [Error: Ready check failed: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - read ECONNRESET]
Redis error: [Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - read ECONNRESET]
Redis error: [Error: Ready check failed: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - read ECONNRESET]
Redis error: [Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - read ECONNRESET]
Redis error: [Error: Ready check failed: Redis connection gone from end event.]
Redis error: [Error: Ready check failed: Redis connection gone from end event.]
Redis error: [Error: Ready check failed: Redis connection gone from end event.]
Redis error: [Error: Ready check failed: Redis connection gone from end event.]
Redis error: [Error: Ready check failed: Redis connection gone from end event.]
````

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Redis log? It seems like this is a Redis issue, that has nothing to do with your Node code - you can't even access it from CLI. Look at the log for the specific error - it may be as simple as a permission issue, or a stuck temp file.

Comment: Also, try running Redis with `redis-server --loglevel debug`